# rails form bootstrap popover data remote

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

i have a  rails form partial that I am showing inside a bootstrap popover. The form shows up and all the fields have expected behavior.

The issue I am running into is that the from has remote => true and keeps submitting as html. I have been trying to resolve this for the past 3-4 hours and tried various things but no wood !

Here is my simple code -

## Partial Div

```
<div id='ops_customer_creation_modal' style='display:none'><%= render :partial => 'customers/ops_creation_form', :locals => { :customer => Customer.new } %></div>
```

## JS function

```
// a method for ops to create a new customer
    $('.ops_create_customer_window').popover({ 
        html : true,
        content: function() {
          return $('#ops_customer_creation_modal').html();
        },

      }).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
          $("#ops-customer-form").parsley(); # to enable parsley
        });
```

## Form tag

```
<%= form_tag ops_create_customer_path, :id => 'ops-customer-form', :class =>
'form-horizontal', :remote => true, :style => 'padding:10px;', 
:authenticity_token => true do %>
```

Is there any way to enable remote submit on a form that is called via popover.

Here is a screen shot of the form. The error is that it is submitting as HTML. I must be missing something obvious here.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you required jquery_ujs in your application.js(or whatever JS sprockets file you are using?)

Comment: yes jQuery_ui is in the list of required files. The remote true is working everywhere on the site. Except when I am calling this form in a bootstrap popover. The popover is not letting any JS execute inside it. Even the parsley validation on the form were disabled.

Comment: sorry i mean jQuery_ujs is required in the list of files.